# Which Star Trek:TNG episode does Data asks Picard whether a human has a moral obligation to use augmented prosthetic?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I remember a scene in an episode of Star Trek: The Next Generation, where Data and Picard are discussing Data and humanity. In particular, whether Picard would have a moral obligation to upgrade himself with e.g. prosthetic eyes better than human eyes, to execute his Starfleet duties to the best of his ability?

Is this part of [The Measure of a Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Measure_of_a_Man_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are correct, it is The Measure of a Man. Data is being asked to submit to a dangerous procedure for the benefit of Starfleet, and questions why biological beings are not subjected to this.

From http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/135.txt. Note: the final conversation (as shown in @PeterSabers answer) differs slightly from the original script.

> ```
>                   PICARD
>           It's precisely because you are
>           a Starfleet officer that they can.
>           We take an oath to serve. In this
>           case this is the form your service
>           is taking.
>
>                   DATA
>           Sir, Lieutenant La Forge's eyes
>           are far superior to human
>           biological eyes, true?
>
>                   PICARD
>           Yes.
>
>                   DATA
>           Then why are not all human
>           officers required to have their
>           eyes replaced with cybernetic
>           implants?
>
>   Picard is utterly at a loss for words. We can see the
>   confusion on his face as he struggles for an answer to
>   this unanswerable remark. Data rises with great
>   dignity.
>
>                   DATA
>               (continuing)
>           I see. It is precisely because
>           I am not human.
> ```

Answer (score 10):

Are you talking about the scene in this very badly named video?

It's from "*The Measure of a Man*", yes.

Comment: It's not only badly named, it's ironically named considering the entire episode is trying to answer the question of whether or not Data is property or not.

Comment: I consider it badly named because in Star Trek, especially TNG, characters don't "own" each other, they educate. Data doesn't own Picard, he discusses a hard topic with him

Comment: @Petersaber - To some people in this world, every discussion, every debate, every polite conversation, is a battle they must win.

Comment: It might be considered wonderfully named.   It doubles the meaning of "defeats" with the irony of the question of the whole episode about ownership of Data

Comment: To me it's just childish. "Pwned!". But that's just my opinion

Comment: @Petersaber Sometimes *owning* someone - taking their preconceptions, biases, prejudices, and personality traits stripping them naked and laying it bare for them in such a way that they can't hide from the truth - ***IS*** educating them. As it is in this case.

Comment: @Shane "to own someone" is very disrespectful and insulting. I highly doubt that scene contained either disrespect or insults.

Comment: @Petersaber Uhh, watch it? Data is calling Picard a bigot. He then get ups and walks away: basically pulls a 'mic drop'. He is about as disrespectful as you can get to your superior in the military without being pulled up on charges.

Comment: @Shane your interpretation implies a level of hostility that was never present between the two characters